# How to tag docker image with release version number from a previous GitHub action job

Tags: github-actions, cicd, semantic-release

I have the following action that first runs a semantic release and then builds a docker image. At the moment the image is tagged with `master` but I want it to be tagged with the release i.e. `v1.0.8`

I assumed that `${{ github.ref_name }}` would refer to the release number that was created in the previous step rather than the branch name.

Is there a different variable I need to be using?

```yaml
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  release:
    permissions:
      contents: write
      issues: write
      pull-requests: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npx semantic-release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  build:
    needs: release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build the Docker image
        run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag gitflow-test-gui:${{ github.ref_name }}
      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1 
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Push the latest Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/ioncoder/gitflow-test-gui:latest
      - name: Push the Docker image with the release tag
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/ioncoder/gitflow-test-gui:${{ github.ref_name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use [`semantic-release`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-release) before, but as I read it releases your Node packages and it takes care of running something like `npm version patch`.

What I would do is to read the new version from `package.json` either with `npm pkg get version` or `cat package.json | jq -r .version` and save the input to a variable that I would [output from my `release` job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs)

```
jobs:
  release:
    outputs:
      pkg-version: ${{ steps.get-version.outputs.pkg-version }}
    permissions:
      contents: write
      issues: write
      pull-requests: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # ...
      - run: npx semantic-release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Export version
        id: get-version
        run: |
          MY_PKG_VERSION=$(npm pkg get version)
          echo "pkg-version=$MY_PKG_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      
  build:
    needs: release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build the Docker image
        run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag gitflow-test-gui:${{ needs.release.outputs.pkg-version }}
```

---

[`github.ref` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts) returned `master` as you are running this workflow on push to `master`:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
```

If you want to run it when creating a Github release, you should use on [`release published`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release) event instead:

```
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
```